# Spring controller isn't binding data from html form

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc, controller

In my current spring-boot project, I have a form which data is handled by by this controller method:

```
  @RequestMapping(value="alterar", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
  public void altera(@ModelAttribute("object") E object, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
    serv.altera(object);
  }
```

and this method call that one in the service class:

```
  public void altera(E e) throws Exception {
        settings.save_settings(e);
    }
```

but when I try submit data through this controller, despite the browser's developer tools shows the fields are being sent to the server, no data is received by the controller (I saw both values for `object` and `result.getModel()`; for both, the value for the fields are null).

Anyone can see what I am doing wrong here?

ps.: the html for the form:

```
<form role="form" class="form" id="form" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/Paypal/alterar">                                            
<div class="field-box">
    <label>http.ConnectionTimeOut</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <input type="text" name="http_ConnectionTimeOut" class="form-control" value="" />
    </div>
</div>
...
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not model attribute defined in html form

Try updating your view as

```
<form role="form" class="form" id="form" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="/Paypal/alterar" modelAttribute="object">
```

Answer (score 0):

Moreover `modelattribute` will just bind your whole class with one single object that is `object` here and will directly give the default value which is `null`. Try using `@ResponseBody` instead.

Comment: I don't get. I alre4ady using RespondeBody here (see code for controller above). What more I can do?

Comment: Use RequestBody for POST AND PUT instead of modelattribute